# getting clipboard support for vim

Tags: vim, clipboard, xterm

I am using vim in a terminal emulator on Ubuntu 14.04.

I have been using it for a while and had been getting along fine, until I had to copy lines from one file to another. After some searching I found what I needed, which was to do:

```
 set clipboard=unnamed
```

However, This wasn't working and neither was explicitly using the * register.
 Turns out, I don't have clipboard support. Here is the output of vim --version
[image: Vim --version outpu]

Note the entries:

```
-clipboard
-x11
-xterm_clipboard
```

So how can I get clipboard support? 
Is it necessary to install a completely new version of Vim?

For now, I am using :read and sed combined to get the line numbers that I want, but I would like a cleaner solution.

Comment: Was the file you wanted to paste to inside or outside vim?

Comment: Inside, but I'd like to be able to do both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clipboard support is only one command away:

```
$ sudo apt-get install vim-gnome
```

But you could simply edit all your files in Vim and yank/put between buffers.

Comment: Will this overwrite my .vimrc?

Comment: No, of course not. As long it's really *your* `.vimrc`, in your `$HOME`.